# Allow python program to accept input with decimal input

Tags: python

I'm actually a beginner in Python and this program that I am working on does not accept decimal input. Every time I change int to input or float it does not run. Also if possible, help me to make my code cleaner.

```
def convert_number_system(input_number, input_base, output_base):
    '''
    returns: int, converted number
    '''
    remainder_list = []
    
    sum_base_10 = 0

    if output_base == 2:
        binary_repr = bin(input_number)
        return (binary_repr[2:])
  
    elif input_base != 10:

        reversed_input_number = input_number[::-1]

        hex_helper_dict = {'a' : 10 , 'b' : 11 , 'c' : 12 , 'd' : 13 , 'e' : 14 , 'f' : 15}

        for index, number in enumerate(reversed_input_number):
            for key,value in hex_helper_dict.items():
                if str(number).lower() == key:
                    number = value
            sum_base_10 += (int(number)*(int(input_base)**index))

    elif input_base == 10:
        sum_base_10 = int(input_number)

    while sum_base_10 > 0:

        divided = sum_base_10// int(output_base)

        remainder_list.append(str(sum_base_10 % int(output_base)))

        sum_base_10 = divided

    return_number = ''

    if output_base == 16:
        hex_dict = {10 : 'a' , 11 : 'b' , 12 : 'c' , 13 : 'd' , 14 : 'e' , 15 : 'f'}

        for index, each in enumerate(remainder_list):
            for key, value in hex_dict.items():
                if each == str(key):
                    remainder_list[index] = value
    else:
        for each in remainder_list[::-1]:
            return_number += each

        return (return_number)
```

Edit: These instructions was added as an alternative. How can I implement this to the code?

1. store input in a character array.
   note: the characters before the decimal point is the integer part and after the decimal point is the fractional part
2. you can now multiply each element of the array with the corresponding powers of R,
3. compute the sum of the products --the sum is the converted value

Comment: You can only convert integers to binary, not floats, like in `bin(input_number)`

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow!  Could you explain what you mean by the fact that the code doesn't run.  Do you get an error?

Comment: If that's the case, how would my program take float inputs? btw this is a number conversion program.

Comment: yeah if I change all the int to float the error will be, "could not convert string to float"

Answer (score 0):

To change an input string into a decimal, you could do `float(input())` and to check if the input is actually a decimal, you could do

```
if not (type(input_number) is float):
  break;
```

If this is in a while loop that repeats until the user enters a valid float, otherwise the program would just terminate.

Comment: can I ask which parts specifically should I change into to that code?

Comment: Well, in your code, it only has a function which takes in the input_number variable which I assume is the number you are inputting so the place where that variable is declared, put a float() around it.